couldn't connect to postgres in GCP VM using pgadmin
I couldn't connect to postgres running in GCP VM using pgadmin. I altered the
listen_addresses=*,
pg_hba to HOST ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 MD5
but still couldn't able to connect. thought maybe because of firewall in my VM, so altered the firewall rules to below, still no use. Can anyone please help me.

You need to provide the exact error message from when you are unable to connect, along with the contents of the Postgres log around that time.

This is my new GCP vm, where I have installed postgres. I tried to connect using pgadmin and getting below error
"Unable to connect to server:
server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request."
I could see the below in postgres log, nothing after this or before.
"2024-12-12 10:49:54 UTC [1912]: [1-1] db=[unknown],user=[unknown],app=[unknown],client=167.103.25.5LOG:  connection received: host=167.103.25.5 port=2265"
